# How to infer the resulting object type from a nested tree of objects/components

Tags: typescript

Given the following structure:

```js
const myForm = {
  widget: "col",
  children: [
    {
      widget: 'row',
      children: [
        {
          widget: 'text',
          prop: 'name'
        },
        {
          widget: 'number',
          prop: 'age'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      widget: 'text',
      prop: 'location',
      optional: true
    }
  ]
} as const

type MyForm = Infer<typeof myForm>
```

I want to infer the following type:

```
{
  name: string
  age: number
  location?: string
}
```

So far, I managed to "walk" the tree of objects, and infer the types for each widget, but I'm stuck on building the final object. Here is my [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIgE5xgXhgbwFAwwDuAlgCYDmAplAFwwBEoANgwDQEzAAWJzZqKmHoBtToXyEpxctTowA5KhBEFHaYR58BQ0eI2SN00pRr0FUKgA8oa-UYAOyh%20bABDOFQX2pAX3VGuD7GsmaKYACucABGVKh2gVJOIC6KbtTeib4%20ALr6-vqGIabyFta2AdLJqQrMIMBuUCTgCRopTeBuzPRQqBFU%20Zx5vjBuEFzg0Hh4UAgOVDAAsshoGNgAkmAAZnEAPLPzIFvwK%20hsuL4AfNMHC5s7qLsAKucASlQQEcxQl1gwnE8YOUhGRxjguLx%20IJhDBBG4yOBmAhRmAECIcjBstIAPwwe5xACCqFQbgQzxECi0UKEChybw%20Xx%20MHoAKBNhBYJg1XoblRmP0uPxqAACs5ntdpPQImAANZgFRgG5zO7bQnE0nPNmWMCg2FUeGI5G8tF0mDvT7fX7YQwiADSMBIYBgMqoCCOMCeOXoQvJttN5sZ12yM2VeNVIrFTyt-0IgOBOs5Jjk5ksNgUmJguOgqEdFGZrPjuvBSbCCkiMTi6ZGuPLsVQ%20cIYCoADc4kA) link. I you hover over the `MyForm` type you will see what I achieved so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the simple stuff. At some point, we will need to *map* from the string representation `"text"` to the type `string` and other types. In your playground, you used a *conditional type* for this. That works, but using a simple map makes it easier to understand and expandable (and the performance is better too ^^).

```
type WidgetToType = {
  "text": string
  "number": number
}
```

I also define a type `FormElement` for the given data structure.

```
type FormElement = { 
  widget: string, 
  children?: readonly FormElement[], 
  prop?: string, 
  optional?: boolean 
}
```

This will make it easier to access properties by indexing the generic type `T` later. We can use the type as a constraint for `T` to do things like `T["prop"]` without needing to *check* if the property exists.

Now to the harder part. We know the resulting type is a flat object.

```
type MyForm = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location?: string | undefined;
}
```

We also know that we can construct such object types with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and that we need a *union* for mapping. So ideally we can create a helper type which will create a *union* from a given type which will look like this:

```
{
    widget: "text";
    prop: "name";
} | {
    widget: "number";
    prop: "age";
} | {
    widget: "text";
    prop: "location";
    optional: true;
}
```

This *union* should contain all the needed information about each resulting property.

To create the *union*, I wrote the *recursive* type `GetPropsDeeply`.

```
type GetPropsDeeply<T extends FormElement> =
  | (T["prop"] extends string ? T : never)
  | (T["children"] extends readonly any[] 
      ? T["children"][number] extends infer U 
        ? U extends FormElement
          ? GetPropsDeeply<U>
          : never
        : never
      : never
    )
```

`GetPropsDeeply` starts at the root of the object type and begins building the *union* by performing two checks. First, it checks if `T["prop"]` is set. If so, we can add `T` to the union. Then it checks if `T["children"]` is set. If that is the case, we convert the `children` tuple to a *union* of children elements by indexing `T["children"]` with `number`. We can now use these union elements in the recursive call to `GetPropsDeeply`.

Here is also a *"hidden"* TypeScript mechanic. By storing `T["children"][number]` inside `U` and checking if `U extends FormElement`, we are [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the union elements over `GetPropsDeeply`.

So instead of having `GetPropsDeeply<E_1 | E_2 | E_3>` (where `E_N` is a union element), we *distribute* over `GetPropsDeeply` resulting in `GetPropsDeeply<E_1> | GetPropsDeeply<E_2> | GetPropsDeeply<E_3>`.

Now to the last part.

```
type Infer<T extends FormElement> = (GetPropsDeeply<T> extends infer U ? ({
  [K in U as K extends { optional: true } 
    ? never 
    : K["prop" & keyof K] & string
  ]: WidgetToType[K["widget" & keyof K] & keyof WidgetToType]
} & {
  [K in U as K extends { optional: true } 
    ? K["prop" & keyof K] & string 
    : never
  ]?: WidgetToType[K["widget" & keyof K] & keyof WidgetToType]
}) : never) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
```

We call `GetPropsDeeply<T>` and store the result in `U`. Since properties where `optional` is `true` are supposed to be optional, we need to construct two seperate [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where one is using the `?` notation and *intersect* them.
For the respective mapped type, we filter out the union elements where `optional` is `true` or `false` respectively. To get the property name, we do `K["prop"]` and we also use our mapping here to get the corresponding type of `K["widget"]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIgE5xgXhgbwFAwwDuAlgCYDmAplAFwwBEoANgwDQEzAAWJzZqKmHoBtToXyEpxctTowA5KhBEFHaYR58BQ0eI2SN00pRr0FUKgA8oa-UYAOyh+bABDOFQX2pAX3VGuD7GsmaKYACucABGVKh2gVJOIC6KbtTeib4+ALr6-vqGIabyFta2AdLJqQrMIMBuUCTgCRopTeBuzPRQqBFU+Zx5vjBuEFzg0Hh4UAgOVDAAsshoGNgAkmAAZnEAPLPzIFvwK+gAfHgA9JfSAHoA-NMHCwDqoVAAKiAfcwvYhgxLDYGPRoKgSGAKJwGJEYnEQTBYbFUHhsjNfjAUOgAKLMKieMCwf4wTgmOSg3oQihsEmaXj8QRge70QRuMjgZgITGrXH4oRQEQ5GmcarMmBgqnCwjtZruZhi6IgEB4txgElo54wADiNAACs4IAARKhUByc3YfGDlIRkcZYuC8glQM5YTgAHxgAAoPiIGNUGDkrTYbeMJZCYPcYJb6GAqAA3OIASndXp9THpOjAAaDljAtpgrPZYE5ozACEFtI0kbTWgZQgDIiRcUD1rz4whO1QMAAqpWjJHe638-bHfzglJIzqoPqUkaTWaELtuxdEoQY-G4uP1wmUUZt5vpMn0fMYJtOxacyHuTi8U6XdhPVOZw456bzR8XUP29s4j2I17DBEABpGAIT-MYYBAr9cBgGVOm6GBen6GARn0SNYx3PsYHoIDfX9GAADIYAAayoBAjkgwMiLDKFCByeg3hKL4fnmYDfTJGgGEIkiyIooCqJ48jjkYuRmN+YZuMAkCwN7CCoODNsYLguUej6BZUOkSNcL9ZwuKI0ihMo7iaKw-ddxgHIxREmgxNY7SOKgPTBL4gSDIo6zPm+cTUUTbDEQ3VBfOgjtfwAeX-HAYGA0C1Tc45QvomBQuAwMRjMoA)

Comment: Wow! It works, but how? I'm eagerly waiting for the explanation.